# R: singular sum of a column

Tags: r, dataframe, sum

I have this data.frame based on two vectors:

```
V<-c(1,2,3,4,5)

X<-c(2,3,1,1,2)
```

I would like to create a new column (AC.X) based on a singular sum of X-column-values. I.e.,

```
AC.X<- c(2+3+1+1+2,3+1+1+2,1+1+2,1+2,2)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is your question? What is the definition of a "singular sum"? What have you tried to achieve the desired result? Please improve your question to make it easier to answer by others.